# JButton Positioning

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, jbutton

Ok so I'm trying to position my JButton but if I set the "this.setLayout" to null my button doesn't show up but if I put a Layout the button appears. I really want to position my button rather than using a layout..
I've tried using a container, a panel(seen below), just regularly.. nothing works :l

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class BingoHelper extends JFrame implements WindowListener, ActionListener{
    JTextField text = new JTextField(20);
    JPanel pnlButton = new JPanel();
    private JButton b; {
            b = new JButton("Click to enter name");
            }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        String fn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Username:");
        String sn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Password:");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome " + fn + " " + sn + ".", "", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        text.setText(fn + " " + sn);
        b.setVisible(false);
        text.setVisible(true);
    } 

    public BingoHelper(){
        super("BINGO");
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(text);
        text.setVisible(false);
        this.add(pnlButton);
        pnlButton.add(b);
        pnlButton.setVisible(true);
        pnlButton.setLocation(800,800);
        b.setVisible(true);
        b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,40));
        b.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        dispose();
        System.exit(0);

    }
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {}
}
```

Comment: `if I set the "this.setLayout" to null...` - Don't use a null layout!!! Swing was designed to be used with [layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). So play with the different layout managers to see how they work and remember that you can also nest layout managers.

Comment: _I really want to position my button rather than using a layout._ No, you don't. Perhaps you do not realise it yet, but you really don't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are [using Null Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html), you must position the JButton using the `button.setBounds(x, y, width, height);` method where `(x, y)` is buttons location and `(width, height)` is button's size. Now lets review your code:

```
        add(text);
        text.setVisible(false);
        //this.add(pnlButton);
        pnlButton.setLayout(null); // setting the null layout to the button panel
        pnlButton.add(b);      
        //pnlButton.setVisible(true); // why do you need it ? it is already true
        //pnlButton.setLocation(800,800);  // weired location, remove it 
        //b.setVisible(true);    // why do you need it? it is already true
        //b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,40));
         b.setBounds(20, 20, 100, 30); // putting setBounds here
        b.addActionListener(this);

         setContentPane(pnlButton);   //set the pnlButton as content pan

    }
```

Comment: while technically correct, not using a LayoutManager is a no-go

Comment: yes that is why i attached a JAVA DOC source which says exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

You are using GrigBagLayout, you should use  GridBagConstraints to add and locate the position of the component.

Please refer the link for more information about Grigbaglayout : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html